# Can't run Firebase starter app tutorial due to filenames that are over 240 characters long

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to learn how to integrate **Firebase** into my app so I'm following along the tutorial Google put out [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0). It's on step 5 where I try to run the code that I get this error:

> Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters : C:\Users\User\Desktop\Android_Projects\Firebase Projects\friendlychat\android-start\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png

So I removed the directory **"res"** just to test it, but for some reason that entire directory was restored when I rebuilt the project. I can't move the directory to another location (to shorten the length) or remove it because it just restores back to this location when I rebuild the project. Has anyone had this issue? Does anyone know how to get this working on Windows? Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a generated directory. Move *the whole project* somewhere with a shorter path.

Comment: @EugenPechanec man I feel dumb. Not sure why I didn't think of this. Thanks it worked!